# Intermittent slow page loads for our portal pages through cloudflare CDN. Any audit/debug tools suggestions?

Tags: performance, web, analytics, cloudflare

I am looking into an issue with our portal pages that uses Cloudflare CDN. Customers are reporting slow page loads intermittently but we are unable to identify the issue.

Whats done so far:

1. Working with cloudflare to see where the issue is
2. No particular resource(css/image/js) is identified to be a problem yet.
3. Client's network is not a problem.

I almost want to add analytics on our end to get visibility for faster insight. Any suggestions on tools that will help for now to debug and in future to more reliability.